# Solr Term Vector Component returns no terms

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I am importing data from MySql.

Here is the field in question looks like in the schema.xml :

```xml
<field name="solr_body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"
  multiValued="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

And here is the configuration in the solrconfig.xml :

```xml
<searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>

<requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">text</str>
    <bool name="tv">true</bool>
  </lst>
  <arr name="last-components">
    <str>tvComponent</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

When I submit url http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?qt=tvrh&q=solr_body:[*+TO+*]&fl=id as per [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent) tutorial, I get usual results, and no terms. I have deleted old index and indexed again after schema change. What is that I am missing. Kindly help.

Edit : Field Type in schema.xml :

```xml
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" 
              ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" 
            ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Could you add the fieldType `text_general`? I assume it is the one from the example, but one cannot know ...

Comment: There is a version mismatch between latest download and documentation. I am changing df to text_general. Is this what I have to do ?

Comment: Could you post the definition of that field type from your schema.xml?

Comment: updated question. please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below default param in your "/tvrh" handler

```
<str name="terms.fl">text</str>
```

df param is used by "/select" handler by default, not by Terms component.
If you are using solr 4.X or higher ,terms component is configured by default.